# iOS - Converting iPhone Build to iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I have a application that I built that was to be build as an iPhone-only application.

Now, I am told that the application has to be made universal now. I will have to make it iPad compatible too (in portrait-only mode). I have been looking for my options right now as the XIBs in this project are heavily loaded with objects so programatically assigning co-ordinates will be a pain.

I am looking for the best, and the quickest approach I should take to make this iPhone app into iPad-compatible app as well.

PS: There is no mainwindow.xib file as the application was built with XCode 4.3 which doesn't create the MainWindow.xib file.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have made duplicate XIBs for iPad for all the XIBs. Now, I am trying to use the naming convention which tells me to change the filename suffix to MyiPadXIB~ipad.xib and when the app is run on iPad, it will automatically take that XIB. This doesn't seem to be happening.

When I open the application in iPad, only a small window appears (the window that appears when iPhone-only app is run on an iPad).

Any solution to this?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to recreate all the xibs with iPad versions.

Comment: If that's the only, and the best way to go, then I have no problems in creating separate XIBs either.

Comment: Yes, I would create separate view controllers. Owen's answer below should help.

Comment: What's the approach of that app? Should the ipad version just look like the iphone, but just scaled up? Then you could query the type of the device as shown below and do the scaling manually, without additional xib's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed a very easy approach where I would just create duplicate XIBs of all the XIBs by doing Build settings > target (iPhone)> right click and choose duplicate.

I would then change the name of the duplicate xibs in this format: "iPhone XIB name"~ipad.xib.

The system would then automatically pick up the XIB according to the device used.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know (there may be a quicker/better approach that i dont know of)

You would create seperate xib files for the ipad

when you init your view controller you check to see what device you are on like so

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.serverSettingsViewController = [[ServerSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ServerSettingsViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.motionJpegViewController = [[MotionJpegViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MotionJpegViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.serverSettingsViewController = [[ServerSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ServerSettingsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        self.motionJpegViewController = [[MotionJpegViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MotionJpegViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
```

And load you iphone or ipad xib file (FYI make sure the xib views are large enough for the ipad)